# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Bearer Auth without Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, bearer-token

I thought I had a pretty simple goal in mind when I set out a day ago to implement a self-contained bearer auth webapi on .NET core 2.0, but I have yet to get anything remotely working.  Here's a list of what I'm trying to do:

- Implement a bearer token protected webapi
- Issue tokens & refresh tokens from an endpoint in the same project
- Use the [Authorize] attribute to control access to api surface
- Not use ASP.Net Identity (I have much lighter weight user/membership reqs)

I'm totally fine with building identity/claims/principal in login and adding that to request context, but I've not seen a single example on how to issue and consume auth/refresh tokens in a Core 2.0 webapi without Identity.  I've seen the 1.x MSDN example of cookies without Identity, but that didn't get me far enough in understanding to meet the requirements above.

I feel like this might be a common scenario and it shouldn't be this hard (maybe it's not, maybe just lack of documentation/examples?).  As far as I can tell, IdentityServer4 is not compatible with Core 2.0 Auth, opendiddict seems to require Identity. I also don't want to host the token endpoint in a separate process, but within the same webapi instance.

Can anyone point me to a concrete example, or at least give some guidance as to what best steps/options are?

Comment: I would love to see a sample of this too.

Comment: Identity it's decoupled from JWT mechanism. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) and [this](https://pioneercode.com/post/authentication-in-an-asp-dot-net-core-api-part-3-json-web-token). Greetings.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Did an edit to make it compatible with ASP.NET Core 2.0.

---

Firstly, some Nuget packages:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
- System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
- System.Security.Cryptography.Csp

Then some basic data transfer objects.

```
// Presumably you will have an equivalent user account class with a user name.
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class JsonWebToken
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }

    public string token_type { get; set; } = "bearer";

    public int expires_in { get; set; }

    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
}
```

Getting into the proper functionality, you'll need a login/token web method to actually send the authorization token to the user.

```
[Route("api/token")]
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    private ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public TokenController(ITokenProvider tokenProvider) // We'll create this later, don't worry.
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    public JsonWebToken Get([FromQuery] string grant_type, [FromQuery] string username, [FromQuery] string password, [FromQuery] string refresh_token)
    {
        // Authenticate depending on the grant type.
        User user = grant_type == "refresh_token" ? GetUserByToken(refresh_token) : GetUserByCredentials(username, password);

        if (user == null)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("No!");

        int ageInMinutes = 20;  // However long you want...

        DateTime expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(ageInMinutes);

        var token = new JsonWebToken {
            access_token = _tokenProvider.CreateToken(user, expiry),
            expires_in   = ageInMinutes * 60
        };

        if (grant_type != "refresh_token")
            token.refresh_token = GenerateRefreshToken(user);

        return token;
    }

    private User GetUserByToken(string refreshToken)
    {
        // TODO: Check token against your database.
        if (refreshToken == "test")
            return new User { UserName = "test" };

        return null;
    }

    private User GetUserByCredentials(string username, string password)
    {
        // TODO: Check username/password against your database.
        if (username == password)
            return new User { UserName = username };

        return null;
    }

    private string GenerateRefreshToken(User user)
    {
        // TODO: Create and persist a refresh token.
        return "test";
    }
}
```

You probably noticed the token creation is still just "magic" passed through by some imaginary ITokenProvider.  Define the token provider interface.

```
public interface ITokenProvider
{
    string CreateToken(User user, DateTime expiry);

    // TokenValidationParameters is from Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
    TokenValidationParameters GetValidationParameters();
}
```

I implemented the token creation with an RSA security key on a JWT.  So...

```
public class RsaJwtTokenProvider : ITokenProvider
{
    private RsaSecurityKey _key;
    private string _algorithm;
    private string _issuer;
    private string _audience;

    public RsaJwtTokenProvider(string issuer, string audience, string keyName)
    {
        var parameters = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = keyName };
        var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, parameters);

        _key = new RsaSecurityKey(provider);

        _algorithm = SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature;
        _issuer = issuer;
        _audience = audience;
    }

    public string CreateToken(User user, DateTime expiry)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(user.UserName, "jwt"));

        // TODO: Add whatever claims the user may have...

        SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Audience = _audience,
            Issuer = _issuer,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_key, _algorithm),
            Expires = expiry.ToUniversalTime(),
            Subject = identity
        });

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }

    public TokenValidationParameters GetValidationParameters()
    {
        return new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = _key,
            ValidAudience = _audience,
            ValidIssuer = _issuer,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0) // Identity and resource servers are the same.
        };
    }
}
```

So you're now generating tokens.  Time to actually validate them and wire it up.  Go to your Startup.cs.

In `ConfigureServices()`

```
var tokenProvider = new RsaJwtTokenProvider("issuer", "audience", "mykeyname");
services.AddSingleton<ITokenProvider>(tokenProvider);

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenProvider.GetValidationParameters();
    });

// This is for the [Authorize] attributes.
services.AddAuthorization(auth => {
    auth.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

Then `Configure()`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    // Whatever else you're putting in here...

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

That should be about all you need.  Hopefully I haven't missed anything.

The happy result is...

```
[Authorize] // Yay!
[Route("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I hadn't even really thought of rolling my own with all of the talk of the new Core2 auth stack etc - I thought this would be ready-made out of the box.  In any case, the only thing missing from your solution is refresh tokens, but that is trivial given the above.  One question - these security tokens are opaque or transparent?  (i.e. When presented with the token, does the auth stack unprotect and attach the identity to the webapi context, or is that an additional step?)  Thanks Mitch!

Comment: It decrypts the token and sets up the context identity for you.  In your controller, `User.Identity.Name` will be the username which was passed into the JWT.

Comment: And yes, I haven't gotten around to refresh tokens yet - it operates fairly separate from the JWT generation code though.  Generate token via some random hash, store it, and check it during a refresh call.  This code was for a quick API I had to whip up back during the .NET Core beta phase.  If someone has a simpler implementation on newer features, that would be great.

Comment: In the Configure() meth I'm getting an error indicating that UseJwtBearerAuthentication() is obsolete and it references some convoluted article (that reads more like an internal discussion between MS coders still in the process of implementing this).  I don't want to use any kind of Identity Server.  Someone please tell me the only way to make this work is not by rolling back to asp.net core 1.1.  MS: why do you keep doing this to us?

Comment: Ok, my codebase is finally onto 2.0, so adjusted my answer to suit.

Comment: Be aware that with .NET Core 2 on Mac OS X you'll get a System.PlatformNotSupportedException when it comes the "var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, parameters);" There are separate threads on this issue on StackOverflow ....

Answer (score 15):

Following on @Mitch answer: Auth stack changed quite a bit moving to .NET Core 2.0. Answer below is just using the new implementation.

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace JwtWithoutIdentity
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    cfg.SaveToken = true;

                    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidIssuer = "me",
                        ValidAudience = "you",
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("rlyaKithdrYVl6Z80ODU350md")) //Secret
                    };

                });

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Token Controller

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using JwtWithoutIdentity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace JwtWithoutIdentity.Controllers
{
    public class TokenController : Controller
    {

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("api/token")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Token(LoginViewModel model)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest("Token failed to generate");

            var user = (model.Password == "password" && model.Username == "username");

            if (!user) return Unauthorized();

            //Add Claims
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, "data"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "data"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("rlyaKithdrYVl6Z80ODU350md")); //Secret
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken("me",
                "you",
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                signingCredentials: creds);

            return Ok(new JsonWebToken()
            {
                access_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expires_in = 600000,
                token_type = "bearer"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Values Controller

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace JwtWithoutIdentity.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            var name = User.Identity.Name;
            var claims = User.Claims;

            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Was looking for something like it. I'm just wondering why you still have the claims and identity if you are not using `User : Identity`.